# NGINX ssl_client_certificate: "FAILED:unable to verify the first certificate"

Tags: ssl, nginx

On my NGINX server I'm using the `ssl_client_certificate  /path/to/clientcert.pem;` option to set up a trusted client certificate.

This `clientcert.pem` file contains two trusted client certificates, the one (A) with the CA certificate of its Issuer, the other (B) one without it. So that's three certificates in total.

When client A makes are request everything works as expected, but when client B makes a request, even though the TLS handshake is successful, NGINX responds with 400 and html message including "The SSL certificate error". The `$ssl_client_verify` variable holds `"FAILED:unable to verify the first certificate"`.

Is there a way to make NGINX accept the client certificate from B without knowing its Issuer? Or am I misunderstanding the problem here?

---

Edit: Feedback on @Seifeddine Besbes' comment asking `openssl s_client` output.

The relevant section is

```
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=ZA/ST=MyState/L=MyCity/O=Org/OU=OrgUnit/CN=example.com/emailAddress=CA@example.com
/C=ZA/ST=MyState/L=MyCity/O=Org/OU=OrgUnit/CN=clientA.example.com
/C=ZA/ST=MyState/L=MyCity/O=OtherOrg/OU=OrgUnit/CN=clientB.example.com
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
```

Comment: can you test  with openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com ? and send us the response plz

Comment: @SeifeddineBesbes please see the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately `ssl_client_certificate` is not the list of client certificates. It is the list of CAs which can be used to sign the client certificates. I suspect that A is working because the CA is present, and not because A's client certificate is present.

Comment: thank you for the output @NieldeWet perhaps there is a problem with the order of your chained certificate?

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm afraid you're right - I tested it by generating another client cert and even though it's not trusted explicitly by NGINX it is accepted because the CA is trusted.